# Periodic intervals

Tags: intervals, period

I have the following structures in my code:

```
class Interval {
    public $start, $end;
}

class Period {
    public $interval, $period;
}
```

They represent a simple and repeating interval, respectively. For example:

```
**** // This is a simple interval [0, 4].
****__****__**** // This is "repeating interval" with period = 2 (each underline means pause between intervals)
```

So period is an infinite set of intervals. The "distance" (or pause) between each of them is constant.

I need a function that accepts an arbitrary interval and period and says whether this interval is inside period or not. "Inside" means that given interval is inside any of intervals in period.

```
function interval_inside_period(Interval $interval, Period $period) {
  return is_inside ? true : false;
}

$period = new Period(new Interval(0, 4), 10); 
// The first 3 intervals in this Period are [0, 4], [14, 18] and [28, 32]
// Like: ****__________****__________****
interval_inside_period(new Interval(15, 16), $period); // === true, is inside [14, 18]
interval_inside_period(new Interval(29, 32), $period); // === true, is inside [28, 32]
interval_inside_period(new Interval( 3,  5), $period); // === false, overlaps but is not inside
interval_inside_period(new Interval(17, 29), $period); // === false, overlaps but is not inside
interval_inside_period(new Interval(11, 12), $period); // === false
interval_inside_period(new Interval(20, 27), $period); // === false
```

The problem is that due to the lack of math experience I have no idea how to implement such function. I've thought about wave functions, specially about [rectangular periodic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) but i have no idea how to describe Period with such function.

A simple Period with equal length and periodicity can be described by [Square wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave):

```
$square_period = new Period(new Interval(0, 2), 2);
// __**__**__**__**
// This function describes such Period.
function is_square_period($n) {
    return ($n >= 0 && ($n / 2) % 2) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

This approach gives opportunity to find if any integer $n lays inside Period or not. But I don't know if this can be used to solve the problem.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see... The offset between two consecutive intervals is `$start + $end + $period`. The start of interval `k` is therefore at `k * ($start + $end + $period) + $start`. By dividing `x` from a given Interval (`new Interval(x, y)`) by `$start + $end + $period` we can calculate our `k`:

```
// this is should be integer division...
$k = ($interval->start - $period->interval->start)
    / ($period->interval->start + $period->interval->end + $period->period);
```

Now we can calculate the bounds of interval `k` and check if the given interval is inside of it.

```
$kStart = $k * (
        $period->interval->start + $period->interval->end + $period->period
    ) + $period->interval->start;
$kEnd = $kStart + ($period->interval->end - $period->interval->start);

return $kStart <= $interval->start && interval->end <= $kEnd;
```

This yields the following with the period and the first interval from your question:

```
$k = (15 - 0) / (0 + 4 + 10) = 15 / 14 = 1
$kStart = 1 * (0 + 4 + 10) + 0 = 1 * 14 + 0 = 14
$kEnd = 14 + (4 - 0) = 18

return (14 <= 15 && 16 <= 18) // true
```

The values for the remaining intervals are:

```
iStart | iEnd | k | kStart | kEnd | result
-------+------+---+--------+------+-------
    29 |   32 | 2 |     28 |   32 | true
     3 |    5 | 0 |      0 |    4 | false
    17 |   29 | 1 |     14 |   18 | false
    11 |   12 | 0 |      0 |    4 | false
    20 |   27 | 1 |     14 |   18 | false
```